# Problem with TRIAC-TDA1085c circuit

Tags: motor, switches, motor-controller, triac, controller

I have a problem with a TDA1085c circuit.

The board has 2 terminal switch with a moving shaft.There are 3 positions. Position 0 (motor stopped) position 1 (right-handed rotation) and position 3 (left-handed rotation). At the same time, moving with the shaft a potentiometer to adjust the speed.
If it has been pressed position 1 or 2 and after turn on the main power switch (230 V), everything is ok with universal motor.
If I turn on the main power switch and press the terminal switch from position 0 to position 1 or 2 the motor starts with high speed and stabilizes in the right speed. The change of direction takes place with relays.

I have tried to change the potentiometer, but the problem is with the spikes from switches and the triac (bta26-700b)
Also I have tried to put electrolytic capacitors on switch contacts and gnd, but the problem remains.

video : https://files.fm/u/qmtjcx3rv
Could you help me?
Thank you[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please draw a schematic.

Comment: Hi.This is an industrial board, i have to do reverse engineering.Its a large board.Do you want the triac circuit(tda1085c) or the control circuit( relays, switches, and uln2003) ?

Comment: " but the problem remains", which problem?

Comment: Hi.You can see the video.The problem is the false speed, at the start, if i press the switch from position 0 to position1 or 2.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is it a control problem or does the TRIAC fail? If the former, you are just confusing the readers with the TRIAC. If the latter, the entire control section is irrelevant.